# Changing html content onclick chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hello and thanks for reading my question. I'll warn you, it will probably seem dull to most of you, but I just can't get it working.

It's about a chrome extension I'm trying to write for my audio stream. Here's what I'm trying to do:

A small icon, that when is clicked once starts playing music, and when is clicked again stops, and so on...

Here's what I've tried:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<div id="music"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and popup.js

```
var well=0
//Executed when the extension's icon is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{ 
    if(well>0)
    {
        var well=0;
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML= '<iframe src="#" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
    }
    else
    {
        var well=1;
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML= '<iframe src="http://electro.piratefm.ro/popup.html" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
    }
});
```

What's happening is that when the extension is loaded, no music plays. When you click it, it starts playing and everything's fine. When you click it again, it stops for a couple of seconds then starts playing again. I need it to stop until you click it again.

Thanks for reading and sorry if it's already been asked or if it's dull.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, my js skills are horrible so it was a dumb mistake, this is the fixed version:

```
var well=0
//Executed when the extension's icon is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{ 
    if(well==1)
    {
        well=0;
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML= '<iframe src="#" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
    }
    else
    {
        well=1;
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML= '<iframe src="http://electro.piratefm.ro/popup.html" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
    }
});
```